# How can I do a MATCH AGAINST with a FULLINDEX against two or more columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM pin
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+red +yellow +blue' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH (front) AGAINST ('+red +yellow +blue' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

If I am correct, this will give me back results that have all words in either title OR front.

Is there a way to design the query so that I also get results where "red" could be in title and "yellow" and "blue" could be in description, or any other combination? I would like results for all three words that are in any combination of any of the columns (but it *must* have all three words, no less).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a composite fulltext index over both columns:

```
ALTER TABLE pin ADD FULLTEXT(title, front);

SELECT *
FROM   pin
WHERE  MATCH(title, front) AGAINST ('+red +yellow +blue' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```